# Function integration on Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to re-write a code from Mathematica to Matlab.

The Mathematica original code is:

[image: Mathematica code sampple]

Ok, no problem until here because I can evaluate the TT[x] function wherever I want (x, x+1, ...) and perform the numeric integral.

I want to do exactly the same thing on Matlab and here comes my problem:

```
TT = simplify(T);
Fx = 7.734*10^(-2)*vpaintegral(TT,x+1,0,Mu)
Result = double(Fx)
```

**Error using sym/vpaintegral (line 131)
Cannot integrate with respect to 'x + 1'. The integration variable must be a
symbolic variable.**

What am I doing wrong? It's possible to evaluate & integrate the function correctly on Mathematica but not on Matlab, is there another way to do it? If I introduce 'x' instead of 'x + 1' the integral works perfectly, as could not have been otherwise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Substitute `x` with `x - 1` and integrate, later substitute back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you replace `TT` by `subs(TT,x,y-1)` and then integrate over new symbol `y`, for example, I am replacing cos(x) in the below function by y and do an integration

```
syms x y
f=3/4*(1+cos(x))^2
vpaintegral(subs(f,cos(x),y),y,0,1)
```